# "FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-20-generic"

Tags: virtualbox

Running the sudo sh vboxsign.sh and getting
"FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-20-generic"

What am I missing? This ran fine last time, but I've since upgraded, and must have forgotten something. I set working directory correctly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try do reinstall "virtualbox-dkms"

```
sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

Comment: Worked! For edification, will you explain why that likely fixed the problem?

Comment: I get: E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-dkms. I have added virtualbox to my sources list, any ideas why this is?

Comment: When I try this, I get `Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel`

Comment: It did not work for me. I had to download again the package from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads and install it with `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961_Ubuntu_eoan_amd64.deb`. I have `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`

Comment: It worked for me. At first I retrieve errors because Virtualbox was running. After closing it, it worked perfectly and my VMs are running again.

Comment: it showing erros `Internal Error, No file name for virtualbox-dkms:amd64
`

Answer (score 12):

For me, reinstalling virtualbox-dkms always gave an error. It was my first time upgrading the kernel, and hadn't upgraded the headers. I needed to also do

```
sudo aptitude install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

and not accept it's first solution (which was to actually do nothing), but accept the second solution which was to upgrade some further library. After that, then

```
sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

worked for me.

Comment: Same, except using `apt` instead of `aptitude` for the first command was enough.

Comment: Showing error `aptitude: command not found`

Answer (score 4):

Based on other answers and the [Virtualbox official documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), here is something that worked:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake bc bison build-essential flex gcc g++ make python -y
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -c | cut -f2) non-free contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.org.list'

wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Reinstallation as mentioned above - had not helped me (within (X)Ubuntu 18.04, with the recently updated kernel).
What worked in my case:

1. Setup key with:

   ```
   wget -q -O - http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Setup repository with:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic non-free contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.org.list'
   ```
3. Download and install the [latest version of `VirtualBox` (with all the extra packages) from this link](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Comment: That's just not how you do it. Setting up repository only to download packages manually is somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem after updating Kernel to 5.4.0-37
and i faced some problems worth mentioning:

turns out you can't install **Guest additions** using old versions of Virtual-box (i guess any version before 5.2) while using this new kernel and Virtualbox-dkms is not supported anymore.
the only way to solve the problem is to remove old version and install Virtual-box 6 from Oracle but this code:`sudo apt-get purge virtualbox` leaves some stuff behind.

after using purge to remove Virtualbox, search "**virtualbox**" in system directory (/) and manually remove everything then install Virtualbox 6 and Guest addition.

that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have this issue with VirtualBox every time I upgrade my kernel.

To fix it do :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms
```

The module will then load successfully.

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```